# How to make a batch file to run on windows

Tags: batch-file

I want to run **php artisan serve** command every time I start my laravel application but I want to make a batch file to run this command from a specific path ie: E:/myfolder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this:

```
E:
cd E:/myfolder
php artisan serve
```

Comment: Oops! Forgot that, Thanks,

Comment: I'm here now C:\Users\Abc\Desktop can't move to E:/myfolder

Comment: check out the answer

Comment: And how can I set an icon for this batch file?

Comment: Right click....(create shortcut) of this file then do this in the created shortcut  (Properties > Change icon) and then you are done!

Comment: How can I perform multiple projects serve from a single batch file.? @Rishav

Answer (score 0):

**local host in ip it will get your ip dynamicly even you can set custom port to host the laravel project**

```
@echo off
cd /d "E:/myfolder"
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 1 %ComputerName% ^| findstr [') do set NetworkIP=%%a
php artisan serve --host %NetworkIP% --port 8000
pause
```